# Gather several 3D objects with textures into 1 blender file

Tags: texturing, export, file-format

I'm a beginner. I have several .blend models with textures, saved separately. I would like to gather them all in a new file, with their textures properly applied.
I thought this would be simple but when I export the models as .obj and import them into a new file, the texture doesn't come with the models. I tried packing the models with textures into a FBX file but same issue when I import: I can't see any texture.

I'm sure there is a simple solution, and I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You mean that you want to use the models in a different application or just move the models to use in a different Machine with Blender?

Comment: I want to keep using Blender. But instead of having 5 different files with a model in each one, I want to create a composition with my 5 models in 1 blender file :-) @Emir

Comment: Why don't you use Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V?

Comment: @Emir yes that's perfect thanks! It was Append I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply import other blender files into a blender-project by using File - Link/Append.

**Link** lets you import other files without being able to change them. If you want to work on them, you have to go into the original file and do it there. It should update automatically in the file where you linked it.
This is very helpful in large projects where you need a good overview of all assets and versions of these assets.

**Append** imports the collection from other .blend files so that you can keep working on them. This is most likely what you rather want from how your question reads.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Till

Comment: Awesome, @tillomat thank you!